# How to understand whether a JsonElement encodes a date

Tags: java, mongodb

In a java program I parse a json document. While I do that I need to analyze the (BSON) type of the value given by a JsonElement. For instance, if I have the following document:

```
{"name" : "John", "age" : 35, "highEducation" : true, "birthDate" : 01/01/1979}
```

I want to detect that the value of "name" is a string, the value of "age" is an integer, the value of "highEducation" is a boolean, and the value of "birthDate" is a date (suppose that 01/01/1970 is how the date is actually represented, although it's something of this shape ISODate("2014-09-17T23:25:56.314Z"), am I right?).

In case I have a primitive, I can check whether it is a string, a number, or a boolean as follows:

```
private static int getBSONType(JsonElement element) {
    int type = BSON.UNDEFINED;
    if ( element.isJsonPrimitive() ) {
        JsonPrimitive primitive = element.getAsJsonPrimitive();

        if ( primitive.isNumber() ) {
            type = BSON.NUMBER;
        } else if (primitive.isString()) {
            type = BSON.STRING;
        } else if (primitive.isBoolean()) {
            type = BSON.BOOLEAN;
        } else  {
            //...
        } 
    } else {
        //...
    }
    return type;
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to understand whether primitive is a date? Ideally, I would be able to add something like

```
        } else if (primitive.isDate()) {
            type = BSON.DATE;
        }
```

but it's not possible. Or I should not get the element as primitive but as something else?

[Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#bson-types-comparison-order) it says that "BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)". So should I analyze more in depth the case of number? Or there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this question as 'mongodb' so I'm going guessing having mongodb related answers might help. (Although your question doesn't appear mongo specific.)

Mongodb has a $type operator that allows you to query documents containing specific types:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

This operator works in both a standard find queries and aggregation queries.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not what I want. I do not want to query a mongo database, instead I want to know if there is a way to understand programmatically which type a value encodes. See my updated question for an example.